# Messed up the Google timed coding assignment

Tags: interviewing

I had prepared quite well for Google and Facebook kind of interviews which focussed on algorithms and problem solving. Google sent me a timed coding assignment of two problems which I had to solve in one hour. However, with the first one I took a wrong path and ended up taking more time than expected and couldn't complete that one neither could I even start the second one. To make matters worse as soon as the time ended I realized the solution to the first problem was a lot simpler. I also believe a bug ended the test 15 minutes too prematurely. However, I have been called for a telephonic interview. Has anyone else been in the same situation. Can I give a strong telephonic interview and rectify the situation or are my chances pretty slim?

Comment: Does that matter? Do your best on the phone interview and see where it leads you.

Comment: Vtc. This is off topic, as it is about company policy. On the other hand, a suuccessful interview means you stay in contact with the company, so do not sweat it. You done good.

Comment: This is REALLY company specific.  We can't tell you what google will do.

Answer (score 3):

> However, with the first one I took a wrong path and ended up taking more time than expected and couldn't complete that one neither could I even start the second one

That's what the assignment is testing. Can you solve the task? If not, how do you recover from an error?

Imagine that you're at work and there's an emergency.  You don't get credit for realising the solution 1 minute after the deadline.

I don't work for Google, so I can't give you advice on *why* they've scheduled a telephone interview.

Don't make excuses for yourself during the interview - but do take the opportunity to explain how you will deal with being under pressure in the future.

Comment: Coding assignments are merely one benchmark of several for comparing potential candidates. The precise "deadline" is less important than the solution, even in real life work situations. I would further add that in the artificial coding assignment, the solution is even less important than the approach taken. Whether or not the OP succeeds depends on how the others did and what else the OP brings to the table as a candidate.